# Removing Bonferroni Outlier Test Results in a loop

Tags: r, linear-regression, outliers, data-cleaning

I modeled my data using linear regression. I want to run Bonferroni outlier test several times and delete the corresponding records from my data. My problem is :I cannot extract the id from outlierResult. Here is the reproducible Code. I want to write a while loop according to the pseudo code. I code in R.

```
# URL <- "http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/data/Galton.csv"
# download.file(URL, destfile = "./galton.csv", method="curl")
galton <-read.csv("galton.csv")
attach(galton)

dim(galton)
head(galton)

##creating outliers
set.seed(1)
random_index <- sample(1:nrow(galton), size = 5, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
print(random_index)
galton[random_index,"Height"] = galton[random_index,"Height"] +100

set.seed(2)
random_index2 <- sample(1:nrow(galton), size = 5, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
galton[random_index2,"Height"] = galton[random_index2,"Height"] +75

set.seed(3)
random_index3 <- sample(1:nrow(galton), size = 5, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
galton[random_index3,"Height"] = galton[random_index3,"Height"] +50


linear_reg <- lm(Height~Father+Mother,data=galton)

require(car, quietly=TRUE)
outlierResult <-outlierTest(linear_reg)
outlierResult


# the pseudocode
# while outlierResult is not empty
#   remove the corresponding records
#   linear_reg <- lm(Height~Father+Mother,data=galton)
#   outlierResult <-outlierTest(linear_reg)
```

Comment: I see this as a programming related problem. Maybe SO would be a better place for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see below. The trick is to note that the outlier result gives the row names if I'm reading it right.

```
library(car, quietly=TRUE)
galton <-read.csv("http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/data/Galton.csv")
attach(galton)

dim(galton)
head(galton)

##creating outliers
set.seed(1)
random_index <- sample(1:nrow(galton), size = 5, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
print(random_index)
galton[random_index,"Height"] = galton[random_index,"Height"] +100

set.seed(2)
random_index2 <- sample(1:nrow(galton), size = 5, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
galton[random_index2,"Height"] = galton[random_index2,"Height"] +75

set.seed(3)
random_index3 <- sample(1:nrow(galton), size = 5, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
galton[random_index3,"Height"] = galton[random_index3,"Height"] +50




currentData <- galton
linear_reg <- lm(Height~Father+Mother,data=currentData)

outlierResult <-outlierTest(linear_reg)
outlierResult

while(length(outlierResult)!=0){
  exclusionRows <-names(outlierResult[[1]])
  inclusionRows <- !(rownames(currentData) %in% exclusionRows)
  currentData <- currentData[inclusionRows,]

  linear_reg <- lm(Height~Father+Mother,data=currentData)
  outlierResult <-outlierTest(linear_reg)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is a problem in the third round of the loop when outlierResult is equal to "No Studentized residuals with Bonferonni p < 0.05". It goes through the Largest rstudent and never gets out of the loop until all the data rows are used.